# Agora - unable to merge video .ts files into one single video file

Tags: python-3.x, video, video-processing, agora.io

I am using agora.io for video calling. I am running script on my localhost.

I am able to record the video successfully but they are multiple .ts files.

I downloaded python script from agora website and ran it. It runs successfully without any error But it does not generate any single video file, in short script run successfully but nothing happens.

No errors, no new file generated.

The code I am using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import re
import os
import sys
import signal
import glob
import parser_metadata_files
import video_convert
from optparse import OptionParser

import traceback


if '__main__' == __name__:
    import sys

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIG_IGN)

    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-f", "--folder", type="string", dest="folder", help="Convert folder", default="")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mode", type="int", dest="mode", help="Convert merge mode, \
        [0: txt merge A/V(Default); 1: uid merge A/V; 2: uid merge audio; 3: uid merge video]", default=0)
    parser.add_option("-p", "--fps", type="int", dest="fps", help="Convert fps, default 15", default=15)
    parser.add_option("-s", "--saving", action="store_true", dest="saving", help="Convert Do not time sync",
                      default=False)
    parser.add_option("-r", "--resolution", type="int", dest="resolution", nargs=2,
                      help="Specific resolution to convert '-r width height' \nEg:'-r 640 360'", default=(0, 0))

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.folder:
        parser.print_help()
        parser.error("Not set folder")

    try:
        print('1')
        os.environ['FPSARG'] = "%s" % options.fps
        print('2')
        parser_metadata_files.cmds_parse(["dispose", options.folder])
        print('3')
        video_convert.do_work()
        print('4')
        parser_metadata_files.cmds_parse(["clean", options.folder])
        print('5')
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

The command I am running is:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 convert.py -f /Users/msmexmac/Desktop/Cloud_Recording_tools/tiles/ -m 3 -p 30
```

I downloaded the script from [this page](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_merge_files?platform=All%20Platforms).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see multiple .ts files is because, after the recording starts, the Agora server automatically splits the recorded content into multiple TS/WebM files and keeps uploading them to the third-party cloud storage until the recording stops.

Make sure to follow the steps in the below-given link for uploading the recorded video:
https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_rest

It is crucial to get the "uploaded" callback to proceed further.